# Regarding " this"and "it"

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, demonstratives

"This"is used to specify objects placed closer.
"It "is used for non living things
I have seen sentences like
This is a pen.
My question is 
It is a pen. ..  .....   is correct?
Why can't we use" **it**" in place of "**this**" since " **it** " also refers to non living things.

Answer (score 1):

*This* is used when pointing out or identifying a nearby object. Once identified, you would use *it.*

What is this? It is a pen.

Whose book is this? It is my aunt's.